# Redis. How would I utilize this in-memory database for my project when most is done with WebSocket Secure

Tags: node.js, json, websocket, redis, in-memory-database

I need to convert over and this will be huge on my project I'm thinking but just want to understand before I approach this new library/technology.

**Will I be able to JSON pub/sub to all servers like this?**

```
{ "app": "closed", "text": "Disconnected." }
```

**If possible could I select which clients get the pub/sub?**

I would like to be able to send all servers messages or specific ones, they'd be broken up into groups if this makes sense so if I wanted to send a pub/sub to HTTPs no other group of servers would regard themselves but they're all in sync.

Apologies ahead of time if this is a repeat but quick searches and couldn't overly find confirmation in timely manor so hoping some experienced users know if this is cake. :)

Comment: If this is not even pub/sub I'd love to understand the terms so I can get to studying. :)

Comment: Before thinking about redis or any other implementation I would suggest you looking into what pub/sub is in itself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern, it answers both of your questions. Yes you can publish whatever you want, and you can also subscribe to whatever you want - it depends on topics, and how you decide to publish it and filter those topics or whatever is the equivalent in the myriad of platforms that follows this paradigm.